# HTML elements are moving badly while animation

Tags: html, css, transition

i have a problem, HTML elements are moving while animation, i have captured 2 pics to guess what i want...

Before animation:
http://i031.radikal.ru/1406/9a/41e9b81ddaed.png
After animation:
http://i057.radikal.ru/1406/1b/c5e3f763fd98.png

all i want is, that after "transition", elements stay on their line...

Here is some HTML and CSS code

HTML

```
<div id="sliderdiv">
    <ul>
    <li>
        <div id="bullets">
        <div class="bullet" id="bul1"></div>
        <div class="bullet" id="bul2"></div>
        <div class="bullet" id="bul3"></div>
        <div class="bullet" id="bul4"></div>
        <div class="bullet" id="bul5"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div id="sliderimages">
            <img src="sliderimages/bilberry.png">
            <img src="sliderimages/dogrose.png">
            <img src="sliderimages/dryedbilberry.png">
            <img src="sliderimages/dryeddogrose.png">
            <img src="sliderimages/dryedherbs.png">
            <img src="sliderimages/wildapple.png">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div id="arrows">
    <div id="slideup"></div>
    <div id="slidedown"></div>
    </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
#sliderdiv{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
    height: 771px;
    width: 100%;
}

#sliderimages{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    height: 771px;
    width: 1187px;
}

#sliderdiv ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

#arrows{
    width: 26px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#slideup{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#slideup{
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 26px;
    height: 18px;
    background-image: url('slideup.png');
    -webkit-transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
}


#slideup:hover{
    background-image: url('slideuph.png');
    -webkit-transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#slidedown{
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 380px;
    width: 26px;
    height: 18px;
    background-image: url('slidedown.png');
    -webkit-transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
}


#slidedown:hover{
    background-image: url('slidedownh.png');
    -webkit-transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.bullet{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #747474;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: none;
    -webkit-transition: background-color, border 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color, border 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-color, border 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-color, border 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color, border 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.bullet:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 350px; 
}

.bullet:hover{
    border-left: 5px;
    border: solid 5px #747474;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    -webkit-transition: background-color, border 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color, border 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-color, border 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-color, border 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color, border 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.bullet:last-child:hover{
    margin-bottom: 350px; 
}

#bullets{
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: How about this: http://jsbin.com/zayinalu/3/edit

Comment: Wow, good trick, ill add border even before and ill change only colour ;) 
please post that answer here and ill mark you as solver...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set initial value for `border` property to `5px solid #FFFFFF` to `.bullet` selector. Assuming here color `#FFFFFF` is the background color of your page (so it looks transparent).

And when hovering over the bullets replace `border` shorthand property with single longhand property `border-color: #747474;` inside the pseudo selector `:hover`, while `border-width` and `border-style` will be inherited from the initial border value `5px` and `solid`

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/zayinalu/3/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your classes:

```
.bullet{
    position: relative;
}

.bullet:hover{
    right: 5px;
    top: -5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: @LukaChumburidze would you mind adding in the rest of your `UL` code. From what I can tell your bullets are shifting, because you're adding a border of 5px when hovering. You need to account for that shift.

Comment: i tried that, but didn't worked, after animation it shifts also from bottom... wait, ill edit and add other code parts...